# Bind content presenter content to a visual element

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have an items control with items source, and i want it to display previews

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                    
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Preview}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Preview is a grid

```
public class Child
{
    public Grid Preview { get; set; }
    public Child()
    {
        Preview = new Grid();
        Preview.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Test"});
        Preview.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to render anything, what am I missing?

Comment: Creating UI elements in your view model isn't MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Preview}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

or

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Preview}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

there is no datacontext, so it didnt display anything.